# How should I handle changing my vague, general question into a specific, answerable one?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, asking-questions, deletion

About a week ago I posted [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/519753/methods-for-computing-finite-part-integrals-when-corresponding-convergent-integr), which in hindsight is vague and over-broad, both for what I really want to know and for what can be reasonably answered in one question. The example is also bad as it doesn't actually fit the cases I am looking at. Luckily, I was awarded a badge for my mistake!

How should I go about converting my original question into a more specific one that can have a reasonable answer? My instinct was to ask a new, more specific question and then delete the old one.

Answer (score 3):

I think the relevant criterion here is how much you'll change the question.

- If it needs to be wholly or mostly rewritten, it's fine to delete it and ask a new question.
- If it's less than (approximately) one paragraph, editing would be better.

The consideration is this easy because there are no votes in play. So the issue of "evading downvotes" isn't relevant here.